# Java printable only printing one page

Tags: java, printing

In a Java project I'm working on I need to print something to the hardware printer using the Java `Printable` interface. The object can span multiple pages. I've converted the object according to the guidelines specified in the http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/printing/index.html lessons. In my code, my printable spans 2 pages. In the `print` method, I have the following code:

```
// ...
if (pageIndex > amountOfPages) {
    return NO_SUCH_PAGE;
}
// ...
```

where `amountOfPages` is the amount of pages my document spans and `pageIndex` is a parameter filled in by the system when calling the `print` method, indicating the printer is requesting that page for printing purposes.
Further down in the same function I always end with a `return PAGE_EXISTS;` in case the `if(...)` falls through, after printing the contents of the page.

However, at runtime, the printer stops printing after the first page. I've added log messages before every return and I notice the return inside the `if` clause is never reached, so the printer stops before it gets the `NO_SUCH_PAGE` signal.

If I check the printer's attributes, it claims no errors occurred. I'm pretty stumped and I don't understand why the printer stops before the job is actually done, or why it thinks the job is done before it is.

Does anyone see something that could point out the reason for this behavior?

Thanks

Comment: Got a working example?

Comment: I figured out the problem. I was using a Pageable (`Book`), but the `Printable`s added to the book that were multi-page weren't fully printed, only their first pages. I've implemented my own kind of Book but I still have some issues. I'll post the code once I get it fully working.

Comment: I may be wrong, but from what I recall, Book requires a Printable per page

Comment: @MadProgrammer, I am facing the same problem.. and I don't know how to go about it. what do you mean by "Book requires a Printable per page" ?? I feel like my problem is solved within those words :)

Comment: @mlwn A `Book` is a collection of `Printable` pages which can have their own formatting (orientation).  In order to be able to print a `Book`, you must supply each page you want to print.  No point supply a single page an hoping to will print...

Comment: @MadProgrammer, you strike one more time  :) ... you don't know how valuable is your help with this project I am doing.. Thanks

Comment: @mlwn Glad some appreciates me ;)

Answer (score 0):

When you implement the Printable interface you should implement some logic to determine how many pages will be printed, for instance:
 `public int numPages(Graphics g,PageFormat pf)` 
If this logic might take a some processing time, you should store the answer since print may be called multiple times - even multiple times per page. Print is likely to call `numPages(...)`  so this is why it's a good idea to store the calculation.

The Printable interface requires you implement a print method that knows what to write to each page: `public int print(Graphics g, PageFormat pf, int page) throws PrinterException`

If you are printing multiple lines of text, you may find the class package `org.jfree.text` helpful. Since the Graphics drawString method will not word-wrap for you, this can be a nice time saver. For instance:

```
        TextBlock notesBlock = TextUtilities.createTextBlock(
              someLongString, plainFont, g2.getPaint());
        notesBlock.setLineAlignment(HorizontalAlignment.LEFT);
        notesBlock.draw(g2, indent, y, TextBlockAnchor.TOP_LEFT);
```

I needed to implement Printable to generate printer output for a list of objects where the printed output for each object could take as much as half a page or as little as a few lines. I did learn most of what I needed from the Oracle Java printing tutorial / docs, but it was a struggle. Calculating where to place the page breaks was the most challenging part and in fact required that I write almost exactly the same code I would do for printing.
If you want some example code from my project, I can post some more here.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The thing I need to print looks more like an invoice, so I don't need blocks of text. If I could say in advance how many pages each document spans that would be great, but the problem is I only know when the print method is called with the corresponding Graphics and FontMetrics. I calculate and buffer the entire print model after that to save time on recurring print calls. I didn't find the function `numPages` you mentioned in the Printable interface, though I have an implementation of `print`.

Comment: I clarified my answer: numPages is not part of the interface, but it makes send to write this method so that you can determine what the range on the page parameter is. If you are simply printing one invoice per page and no invoice can ever span two pages then your task is much simpler than mine. Buffering may not be required. I just wrote directly to the Graphics context and even on 40 page documents my code was very performant.

Comment: Ah thanks. Normally, an invoice would only be on one page but in some exceptional cases it can span two. Right now I am calculating the entire print model in the first call to `print` using some class variables, and one of them is the amount of pages. The thing is, everything is working fine if I'm adding the printable as a print job to the printer, but if I group multiple into a book, only the first page is printed. But I think @MadProgrammer's response explains the problem :)

Comment: @Thorn Can you please post the example code you mentioned in your answer, thank you :)